# Global symbol require explicit package name Error on printing data to csv using Text::CSV?

Tags: perl, csv

I am having trouble writing data to a csv file using the `Text::CSV` module. I am trying to create a header.
Here is the code:

```
     use strict;
     use warnings;
     use Text::CSV;

     my $prefix="SP_RECON_";
     my $spident=12345;
     my $today;
     my $datetime;
     my $dbh;
     our $rowcount=0;

     $today=GetCurrentDate();


     my $filename=$prefix . $spident . '_' . $today;
     my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, eol => "\n" });
     my @array =   ("RecordId","FileFormatVer","ServiceIdentifier","BatchDate","BatchNum","TimeStamp");

     formatHeader();

     sleep(3);
     changeExtensionReady();


     sub GetCurrentDate
     {
     my($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
     $today=sprintf "%04d%02d%02d",$year+1900,$mon+1,$mday;
     $datetime=sprintf "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d",$year+1900,$mon+1,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec;
     return $today;
     }


     sub changeExtensionReady
     {
     my $value=rename ("$filename.busy","$filename.ready") or die "Unable to rename: $!";
     print $value;
     }

     sub formatHeader
     {
     open my $fh, ">>:encoding(utf8)", "$filename.busy" or die "$filename.busy: $!";
     $csv->print($fh,$array);
     close $fh or die "$filename.busy: $!";
     }
```

Above code is giving me compilation error like

```
<b>Global symbol "$array" requires explicit package name at
C:\onebal\scripts\reportGen.pl line 47.
Execution of C:\onebal\scripts\reportGen.pl 
aborted due to compilation errors.</b>
```

I am not able to figure out what the problem with **csv->print** is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `@array` and `$array` are different. The first is an array, the second is a scalar.

`Text::CSV`'s `print` method wants an array *reference* (pointer to an array). You can create that from a named array using the `\` operator, or you can create a reference to an anonymous array using the `[ ... ]` constructor.

So in your case, change your code to

```
 $csv->print($fh, \@array);
```

I would also recommend passing parameters to functions and taking advantage of return values instead of relying on global variables.

**More on References**

- [Perl References Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [Perl References Reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an array reference to `print`.  Change:

```
 $csv->print($fh,$array);
```

to:

```
 $csv->print($fh,\@array);
```

The reason for the error is that you use `strict`, but you do not have a scalar variable named `array`.  You only have an array variable named `array`.